# python db2 ibm_db simple select query won't execute

Tags: python, db2

Env: 
Python 3.7 64bit 
Windows Server 2012
DB2 v 11.1.2, 
ibm_db module ver 3.0.1

Code:

```
   oCon = ibm_db.connect(ConnectString)
   if oCon:
      sSQL = 'Select 1 as X From SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1'
      oStmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(oCon,sSQL)   #  Offending line
      print('Yee haw! Finally made it to this line')
```

The offending line just exits the program immediately like nothing happened without raising an exception.  Also i've seen other people report the other issue of after installing and importing the ibm_db about continuous pylint warnings 'ibm_db' has no 'connect' member yet it executes the connect method.  Someone may ask why not just use pyodbc.  I need to fetch blob/clob columns from DB2 and pyodbc indicates it/the ibm odbc driver does not support those data types yet.

Comment: I would recommend to open an issue here: https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/

Comment: added added the version information as far as db2-client well if you use the long dsn string connect method of the ibm_db.connect method it uses whichever client comes with the module.  If you have a locally cataloged database you can just use the database/user/pwd... .I've tried both... same behavior.

Comment: Works correctly for me with ibm_db 3.0.1 and Db2 v11.1 and the Db2-client is V11.1.4.4 on Windows x64.  You may have a configuration problem.  Use a CLI trace to see what is happening under the covers, the Db2-Knowledge-Centre explains how to configure a CLI trace.

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
oCon = ibm_db.connect(ConnectString)
```

should be:

```
oCon = ibm_db.connect(ConnectString, '', '')
```